# I have a problem with object handling in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Error:

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

```
class Category{
  final String name;
  final int numOfCoure;
  final String image;

  Category(this.name, this.numOfCoure, this.image);
}

var categoriesData = [
  {"name":"Lúa", 'course': 17, 'image' :"data\\images\\lua.png"},
  {"name":"Ngô", 'course': 25, 'image' :"data\\images\\ngo.png"},
  {"name":"Rau", 'course': 13, 'image' :"data\\images\\rau.png"},
  {"name":"Hoa", 'course': 17, 'image' :"data\\images\\hoa.png"},
];


List<Category> categories = categoriesData
    .map((item) => Category(item['name'], item['course'], item['image']))
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use named parameter and it will solve your problem.

```
class Category{
  final String? name;
  final int? numOfCoure;
  final String? image;

  Category({this.name, this.numOfCoure, this.image});
}

var categoriesData = [
  {"name":"Lúa", 'course': 17, 'image' :"data\\images\\lua.png"},
  {"name":"Ngô", 'course': 25, 'image' :"data\\images\\ngo.png"},
  {"name":"Rau", 'course': 13, 'image' :"data\\images\\rau.png"},
  {"name":"Hoa", 'course': 17, 'image' :"data\\images\\hoa.png"},
];


List<Category> categories = categoriesData
    .map((item) => Category(
        name: item['name'], 
        numOfCoure: item['course'], 
        image: item['image'],
    ))
    .toList();
```

Make sure to add nullable character in front of the field declared in Category class as you haven't initialized them in constructor.

Comment: No. It don't solove my problem

Comment: The parameter 'name' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dartmissing_default_value_for_parameter
{String name}

Comment: This is because you've marked all fields in category as NON-NULL. Just add ? after the type and it will solve the problem.

class Category{
  final String? name;
  final int? numOfCoure;
  final String? image;

  Category({this.name, this.numOfCoure, this.image});
}

Comment: Hey will you please marked as answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a type

```
class Category{
  final String name;
  final int numOfCoure;
  final String image;

  Category(this.name, this.numOfCoure, this.image);
}

var categoriesData = [
  {"name":"Lúa", 'course': 17, 'image' :"data\\images\\lua.png"},
  {"name":"Ngô", 'course': 25, 'image' :"data\\images\\ngo.png"},
  {"name":"Rau", 'course': 13, 'image' :"data\\images\\rau.png"},
  {"name":"Hoa", 'course': 17, 'image' :"data\\images\\hoa.png"},
];


List<Category> categories = categoriesData
    .map((item) => Category(item['name'] as String, item['course'] as int, item['image'] as String))
    .toList();
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was solve

Comment: How was it solved?